# How to create a struct from columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

so i have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

and i want to achieve one that looks like :

```
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

How can i achieve that ? i created the case class for the second structure but i don't know to map the first dataframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `struct` function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newdf = df.select(
  $"id", struct($"os_infos", $"product_infos", $"vendor_infos") as "data")
```

Comment: how can you specify the type of a struct? i.e. if vendor_infos is a double